# Does GCC support command files

Tags: linux, gcc, g++, cygwin

MSVC compilers support [command files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x2khzsa1.aspx) which are used to pass command line options. This is primarily due to the restriction on the size of the command line parameters that can be passed to the [CreateProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682425(v=vs.85).aspx) call.

This is less of an issue on Linux systems but when executing cygwin ports of Unix applications, such as gcc, the same limits apply.

Therefore, does anyone know if gcc/g++ also support some type of command file?

Comment: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Options.html

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Sure!

```
@file
           Read command-line options from file.  The options read are inserted
           in place of the original @file option.  If file does not exist, or
           cannot be read, then the option will be treated literally, and not
           removed.

           Options in file are separated by whitespace.  A whitespace
           character may be included in an option by surrounding the entire
           option in either single or double quotes.  Any character (including
           a backslash) may be included by prefixing the character to be
           included with a backslash.  The file may itself contain additional
           @file options; any such options will be processed recursively.
```

You can also jury-rig this type of thing with `xargs`, if your platform has it.

Comment: that makes me feel a bit foolish, I had a poke around the man page for gcc and couldn't find anything :(